# M key function changed while working

Tags: 3d-view

in 2.83.0 you can move objects to other collection with the M key.
But while I was working it changed to this:
When I press the M key it says:remove from local view. And objects set to display as bounds are visible in rendered view.
Others set to textured are invisible.[image: the invisible object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local view, accessed by pressing "/" on the numpad, isolates the view to only show selected objects. Think of it like hiding all of the layers in something like Photoshop, but leaving only the one you're working on.

When in local view, move only lets you leave local view. Most likely because it puts the object in an isolated collection.
You can get around this though, by splitting your view, which should have the rest of the scene, then you can move normally while your mouse is hovered over the section with the rest of the scene.

You can even add objects to your local view by selecting all in local view, and adding the objects you want to the current selection from the view with the whole scene. Then just exit and re-enter local view.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer.